# how do fetching and then inserting from multi check boxes in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am going to fetching table values in a html table along checkbox in each row  and then inserting values in another database table from multi check boxes in php.

Only the values of checked boxes should be submitted to that table.
db name "laboratory":

1. test: fetching values.
2. package: inserting table.
3. view

   [image: test table: fetching values]
   [image: package table:inserting values]
   [image: view]

   Status 
    
   Active
   Inactive

   ```
    <?php
   $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","laboratory") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

    $query="SELECT *  FROM test";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if ($result) {
    while ($record=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   ```

Comment: For one thing, you're mixing different mysql apis, you can't do that.

Comment: What have you tryed thus far? Please share that with us. Also, you should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to follow this code and implement in your program . Hope that this will cooperate you much

```
            if(isset($_POST['name'])){
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $status = $_POST['status'];
                if(empty($name) || empty($status)){
                    echo "Field Must Not be empty";
                } else{
                    $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
                    if($conn){
                        $query = "SELECT *  FROM userdata limit 5";
                        $stmt = $conn->query($query);
                        $val = '<form action="" method=""> ';
                        $val .= '<table> ';

                         if ($stmt) { ?>
                         <form action="" method="post">
                         <table>

         <?php  while ($result=$stmt->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $result['post']; ?></td>
                            <td><input value="<?php echo $result['post']; ?>" type="checkbox" name="check[]" /></td>
                        </tr>       

              <?php } ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Actual Price </td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Final Price</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="actual"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="discount"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="final"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td><textarea name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel" /></td>
                    </tr>

              </table>

               </form>

             <?php }}   }}?>
             <?php
                if(isset($_POST)){
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($_POST);
                    echo "<pre>";
                }

             ?>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to decide that what are you using either mysqli or mysql, if you are using mysqli then you have to improve your code

```
 $query="SELECT *  FROM test";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 if ($result) {
 while ($record=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

and when you want to `insert` the checked data will be inserted in **package table**. If **package table** in *another database* then you have to give us the full detail i mean tell us the *database name* **of package table**.